How to filter documents in OpenSearch by same propery using AND (filter/must)?
Using this index:
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "body": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "subjects": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "path_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

And adding these 3 documents:
POST test/_doc
{
  "id": "1",
  "body": "topic 1",
  "subjects": [
    {
      "id": "calculus-ii",
      "path_id": ["math", "advanced-math", "calculus-ii"]
    },
    {
      "id": "calculus-iii",
      "path_id": ["math", "advanced-math", "calculus-iii"]
    }
  ]
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "id": "2",
  "body": "topic 2",
  "subjects": [
    {
      "id": "calculus-i",
      "path_id": ["math", "advanced-math", "calculus-i"]
    },
    {
      "id": "calculus-ii",
      "path_id": ["math", "advanced-math", "calculus-ii"]
    }
  ]
}

POST test/_doc
{
  "id": "3",
  "body": "topic 3",
  "subjects": [
    {
      "id": "equations",
      "path_id": ["math", "basic-math", "equations"]
    }
  ]
}

I want to search based on the nested property subjects.path_id, only documents that have both subjects: calculus-ii and calculus-iii.
When I use should it finds both topics 1 and 2. Which means that the structure of the search input is setup correctly:
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "subjects",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "subjects.path_id": ["calculus-ii"]
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "subjects.path_id": ["calculus-iii"]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

However, when I change should to either must or filter, the result is empty.
How can I change this behavior from OR to AND?

The problem seems to be with the nested property. The query worked as expected after changing to:
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "subjects",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "subjects.id": "calculus-ii"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "subjects",
            "query": {
              "term": {
                "subjects.id": "calculus-iii"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

